# How to use proxyTable in vuejs2?

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I'm learning to use Vue-cli webpack. I want my app to be able to access a PHP backend API using the dev server.
The backend API is hosted by Apache on the same computer.

For my test, I created a very simple PHP script, which I can access with the url `http://localhost/php/script.php`

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json");
$data = [
  'type' => 'Car',
  'brand' => 'Ford',
  'color' => 'Blue'
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

In fact, in my Apache httpd server the folder php is a sym link for the static folder in my vue application.

In my vue application, which I created using the command `vue init vuetifyjs/webpack vuetestproject` on my Desktop, I have a component Foo.vue with the following code:

```
var axios = require('axios');
axios.get('/static/script.php', { data: "some data" })
   .then(function (response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS');
      console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(error.message);
   });
```

Then, after installing a few resources like axios, I start my node server by executing the command `npm run dev`.

When accessing my app on `http://localhost:8080/#/foo`, I can see that the axios request is being executed. I am getting a SUCCESS message in my console, meaning that axios is getting a response. However, this response is not what I expect. When I look at the object displayed in my console, it seems that the PHP code is not being interpreted. The data property of response contains instead the content of the script.php file, just like if it was a .txt file.

Note that I edited the proxyTable in config/index.js for my vue app:

```
    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
      '/static': {
        target: 'http://localhost/php',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },
```

I looked at the information on http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html, and also several other sources that I found. But I didn't manage to make it work.
I'm pretty sure that my problem lies somewhere in this proxyTable.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Try moving your PHP script out of `/static` and into some other directory.  I believe the `assetsSubDirectory : 'static'` is overriding your `proxyTable`.

Comment: I moved my PHP script to the folder `/scripts` and I adapted the symlink.
The axios url in my component Foo.vue is now `/scripts/script.php`.
My proxyTable is now:
`proxyTable: {
      '/scripts': {
        target: 'http://localhost/php',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },`

No success :(
Now I got a `GET http://localhost:8080/php2/script.php 404 (Not Found)` error in my log.
Note that the url http://localhost/php/script.php is still working when I access it directly.

Comment: I got it!
I had to add `pathRewrite: {'^/scripts': '}` to the proxyTable. I already tried this before, but as you said it doesn't work when my script is in the /static directory. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer in case someone else runs into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't serve your PHP scripts out of the same directory that you have defined to be your `assetsSubDirectory`.  Doing so will undermine the proxy and cause items in that directory to be served as static documents rather than proxied through the PHP server.

Instead, server your scripts out of another directory, like "scripts", and define that as the path to proxy.  Additionally, as you said, add in a `rewrite` property:

```
// Paths
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '/',
proxyTable: {
  '/scripts': {
      target: 'http://localhost/php',
      rewrite: {'^/scripts': ''},
      changeOrigin: true
  }
},
```

Use the new proxy:

```
axios.get('/scripts/script.php', () => {...});
```

Comment: what if the target is in https, I am getting a 504.